Extending triangulations on surfaces
Suppose that $M$ is a surface (i.e., connected topological 2-manifold, I am willing to assume compact, but possibly with boundary), $K$ a finite simplicial complex, and $f$ an embedding of $K$ into $M$, by which I mean a homeomorphism from a geometric realization of $K$ into $M$. Must there exist a simplicial complex $K'$ which contains $K$ as a subcomplex (not allowing any subdivisions) and a homeomorphism $f'$ of $K'$ onto $M$ which extends $f$?
There are a few posts on MO about extending triangulations for smooth or PL manifolds and so should apply in the topological setting in dimension 2, but what I've gathered from them and other sources is that triangulations of the boundary $\partial M$ can be extended to triangulations of $M$. However, as the given $K$ may not have a nice boundary in $M$, I am not sure if that can be applied here, in addition to issues caused by needing to "smooth" the given $f$. I am not a topologist, so I may be missing something more straightforward. References always appreciated.

It is essentially in the appendix to David Epstein's 1966 Acta Math. paper: He proves this for curves but this proof can be either adapted to general subcomplexes or used to prove the general result.

@MoisheKohan This is helpful. Any chance you (or anyone else) know of a more quotable reference? I was hoping to just cite this as a lemma somewhere.

I do not. Did you check Moise's book?
